# Install Printer Remotely

Tags: powershell, printing, parameters

### I am currently working in Powershell. I have created a Script that allows me to install the specified printer to any given machine on our network. However, I need help with adding Parameters(Variables) so that I do not have to go back into the code each time and manually change the Printer and Its Driver/IP.

```
<# Declare name of the Port #> 
$portName = "TCPPort:xx.xx.xx.xx"
<# Declares the name of the Printers Driver #>
$printDriverName = "HP LaserJet Pro M402-M403 PCL 6"
<# If the printer exists, get the port for it, and assign the name of it to -Name $portname #> 
$portExists = Get-Printerport -Name $portname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
<# If the Port does not exist, Add the provided port name, assign it as the Printerhostaddress #>
if (-not $portExists) {
  Add-PrinterPort -name $portName -PrinterHostAddress ""
}

$printDriverExists = Get-PrinterDriver -name $printDriverName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
<# Once the PrintDriver is obtained, Add the Printer, assign the name,portname, and driver name. Install to designated system #>
if ($printDriverExists){
  Add-Printer -Name "CRCHRDirHP2" -PortName $portName -DriverName $printDriverName
}else{
  Write-Warning "Printer Driver not installed"
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2#functions-with-parameters You're really there, just need to add a param block and that's it

Comment: Thanks for the Link, Like I mentioned Im new to powershell and have not coded in a few years since university. I'm having trouble figuring out where in my code I should input my parameters. Thanks for your help

Comment: That link provided by Santi shows you just that. A param block will always be at the top of your script before actual functional code.

Comment: Thanks you two, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example on how I would write a parameter for $portName or $printDriverName?

Comment: I'll answer your question, just need to know if `"CRCHRDirHP2"` is a constant value

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon No it is not - "CRCHRDIRHP2" is the name of our Printers on the Network, $portName in the code is hidden(for obvious reasons) however the IP in my current code is that printers IP.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how your code would look if it was a function, I've changed the `if` statements for [`try / catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally) statements. The function is using [`[cmdletbinding()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7.2#:%7E:text=The%20CmdletBinding%20attribute%20is%20an,the%20parameters%20of%20compiled%20cmdlets.), this will allow you to use [CommonParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.2#:%7E:text=The%20common%20parameters%20are%20a,an%20effect%20on%20all%20cmdlets.), in example, `-Verbose` if you want to display the `Write-Verbose` comments.

```
function Install-Printer {
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$PrinterName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$PortName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$DriverName
)

    try
    {
        Write-Verbose 'Attempting to get Printer Port'
        # If this fails, it will go to `catch` block
        $null = Get-Printerport -Name $PortName
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Verbose 'Port does not exist. Adding new Printer Port.'
        Add-PrinterPort -Name $PortName -PrinterHostAddress ""
    }
    try
    {
        Write-Verbose 'Adding printer...'
        $null = Get-PrinterDriver -Name $DriverName
        Add-Printer -Name $PrinterName -PortName $PortName -DriverName $DriverName
        Write-Verbose 'Printer added successfully.'
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Verbose 'Failed to add printer, error was:'
        $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
    }
}
```

- Usage:

```
Install-Printer -PrinterName "CRCHRDirHP2" -PortName "TCPPo...." -DriverName "HP LaserJet..."
```

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate you taking the time to work with me on this!

Comment: @BrokerMorty Happy to hep. I added a new parameter for the printer name. If the answer was helpful please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Santiago's answer, if you have some source for the variables it would make things a lot easier. For instance consider the following CSV file 'printers.csv' in C:\Temp:

```
name,portName,driverName
CRCHRDirHP2,TCPPort123,HP LaserJet
CRCHRDirHP3,TCPPort1234,HP LaserJet
CRCHRDirHP4,TCPPort12345,HP LaserJet
```

Now we import the file and start looping through the printers to call the function that Santiago made and use the variables from the input file.

```
$printers = Import-CSV C:\Temp\printers.csv
foreach($printer in $printers){
    Write-Verbose "Processing printer $($printer.name)"
    try{
        Install-Printer -PrinterName $printer.name -PortName $printer.portName -DriverName $printer.driverName
    }catch{
        Write-Verbose "Printer $($printer.name) failed with error: $_"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, guys! I will see if I can write up a CSV source file.

Comment: Oops, had to make a little adjustment to the aligning of the CSV file but you get the point ;)